# How does this nested fold_left work? and what is ~f: and ~init:?

Tags: ocaml

I have this code snippet in Ocaml which is taken from [here](https://github.com/cornell-netlab/yates/blob/ffab7bcc060bcd3b1e094100d0fa8e3253d7eadf/test/Test_Routing.ml#L9). I know it fills a data structure for a demand (traffic matrix) with a the specified value and when the two hosts are the same it just fill the value with 0. In python or in any imerative language, we would use two for loop one inside another to do the task. I assume this is the reason we have two (fold_left) in this code in which each one is equivilant to a one for loop (I might be mistaken!). My question is how this code works? and what is ~f: and ~init:? are these labels. If they are labels why the compiler complains when I remove them or when I change them? even when I put these arguments in the right order?! 
I have finished one book and have watched alot of youtube videos but still find it difficult to understand most of Ocaml code.

```
let create_3cycle_input () =
 let topo = Net.Parse.from_dotfile "./data/topologies/3cycle.dot" in
  let hosts = get_hosts topo in
   let demands =
     List.fold_left
     hosts
     ~init:SrcDstMap.empty
     ~f:(fun acc u ->
      List.fold_left
        hosts
        ~init:acc
        ~f:(fun acc v ->
            let r = if u = v then 0.0 else 53. in
            SrcDstMap.set acc ~key:(u,v) ~data:r)) in
(hosts,topo,demands);;
```

Comment: They are [Labelled arguments](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/labels.html#Labelled-arguments) and if the compiler complains, then you might have broken the syntax somewhere: try with smaller examples, pay attention to error messages (they can be cryptic) and write your own functions (do not only copy existing ones). You need to practice a little bit (https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/), but this is going to be easier with time. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, read my [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975359/how-do-i-use-list-fold-left/55975461#55975461) that explains how `fold_left` works. Once you understand how a single fold works, we can move forward to the nested case (as well as to the labels).

When you have a collection of collections, i.e., when an element of a collection is another collection by itself, and you want to iterate over each element of those inner collections than you need to nest your folds. A good example, are matrices which could be seen as collections of vectors, where vectors are by themselves are also collections.

The iteration algorithm is simple,

```
state := init
for each inner-collection in outer-collection do
   for each element in inner-collection do
      state := user-function(state, element)
   done
 done
```

Or, the same in OCaml (using the Core version of the fold)

```
let fold_list_of_lists outer ~init ~f =
  List.fold outer ~init ~f:(fun state inner -> 
    List.fold inner ~init:state ~f:(fun state elt ->
       f state elt)
```

This function will have type `'a list list -> init:'b -> f:('b -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'b`
and will be applicable to any list of lists.

Concerning the labels and their removal. The labels are keyworded arguments and enable passing arguments to a function in an arbitrary manner, which is very useful when you have so many arguments. Removing labels is sometimes possible, but could be disabled using a compiler option. And the Core library (which is used by the project that you have referenced) is disabling removing the labels, probably for the good sake.

In general, labels could be omitted if the application is total, i.e., when the returned value is not a function by itself. Since `fold_left` returns a type variable, it could always be a function, therefore we always need to use labels with the Core's List.fold (and `List.fold_left`) function.

Comment: One should probably also note that it is never possible to remove labels on a `fold_left` because its return type might be a function. Thus `fold_left collections x y` might be a partial version of `fold_left collection x y ~init ~f`.